# How to play video from the specific localized raw ex: raw-nl/intro.mp4

Tags: android

I am facing the below issue.
My application is supporting 3 different(es, be, fr-be) localizations. I have an `intro.mp4` video in the following raw folders

1. `raw/intro.mp4`
2. `raw-es/intro.mp4`
3. `raw-be/intro.mp4`
4. `raw-fr_rBE/intro.mp4`

below code is to set and play video

```
String uriPath = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.intro;<br>
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
video_view.setVideoURI(uri);
```

If I set the application locale to default (**raw/intro.mp4**), the video is playing fine. But if I change the locale to other(es, fr_rBE) videos are not playing from the specific locale.

Tested in the OS-7, OS-8 and OS-9